# One hundred people each with either all white hair or all black hair are arbitrarily seated in four rooms

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, pigeonhole-principle

> One hundred people each with either all white hair or all black hair
> are arbitrarily seated in four rooms. Then the most significant number of
> people with the same colour hair we can be sure of finding in at least
> one of these rooms is

I know we should use the pigeonhole principle,

if I consider 50 people with black hair and 50 people with white hair, I take 50 people(of either all black or all white hair) and there are 4 rooms

so I do $\lceil 50/4 \rceil = 13$

is it the correct way?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: sorry for that, let me edit the description

Comment: It doesn't look like you're allowed to assume the hair colors are exactly 50+50. But there are $4\times2=8$ possible (room, color) pairs and 100 people assigned to these 8 groups...

Comment: @Karl so by this $\lceil 100/8 \rceil$ gives 13 ?

Comment: Yes. If each group had less than 13 then we'd have at most $8\times12=96$ people, but there are 100.

Comment: @Karl do you want to consolidate your comments into an answer?